# Need help understanding how to find the limit of a specific type of sequence

Tags: calculus

I've been having trouble for some time now on how to find the limit of a sequence similar to this one:

$a_n = \sqrt 8+\frac54a_{n+1}$

How does one approach something like this? I've had the same trouble with functions, for example, find $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$
where
$f(x) = f(x-2) + 2x^2)$

I made these examples just now, so if you could, explain to me how should I solve problems like these in general. Thanks for your time.

That was really helpful!! :) Thank you

Comment: Let $a'=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$.  It thus follows that$$a'=\sqrt8+\frac54a'$$which is simple to solve.  Now you just have to prove convergence.

Comment: Your recurrence relation is written kinda backwards. Not that you can't do that -- you can. But it's usually done the other way around, by providing a formula for a subsequent element of the sequence in terms of the preceding one(s). If we actually start with the formula as you gave it, it actually makes the question a bit more interesting, but then your very first step should be to turn around and express $a_{n+1}$ in terms of $a_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *know* there's a limit going in, then you can just equate $a_n$ with $a_{n+1}$ as $n \to \infty$.  (The limits of $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ must be equal if they exist.)  Call that limit $a$; then

$$
a = \sqrt8+\frac54 a
$$

$$
-\frac{a}{4} = \sqrt8
$$

$$
a = -4\sqrt8 = -8\sqrt2
$$

In many cases, however, you are expected to show that there is a limit.  That *could* be done by first finding the limit (if it exists) by the method above, and then showing that whatever value $a_n$ currently holds, $a_{n+1}$ must be closer.  But there are other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the already given answers, let me emphasize that proving that the limit exists *before* you attempt to find it is a **really big deal**. The formula that you gave,
$$a_n=\sqrt{8}+\frac{5}{4}a_{n+1},$$
is equivalent to
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{4}{5}\left(a_n-\sqrt{8}\right),$$
and we can show that this sequence converges (regardless of the initial term, which, technically speaking, should be provided). But if we set up another sequence as
$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{8}+\frac{5}{4}a_n,$$
then the equation to find its "limit" would be the same, and one might erroneously conclude that the limit is also $-8\sqrt{2}$, while in fact this limit doesn't exist.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily agree that one must show that the limit exists *before* you try to find it.  Sometimes knowing what it is helps to prove it.  But I do agree that without that proof (or some other assurance that the limit exists, and is unique in cases such as this), the demonstration is incomplete.

Comment: @BrianTung: If we rephrase it as "knowing what it _would be_ helps to prove it", then I agree with you. :-)

Comment: Well, if it merely would be, but isn't, then there's nothing to be proven. :-P  But yes, I agree with you too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming limit exists, the values $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ are nearly the same for large $n\in\mathbb N$.
Thus, denoting alleged limit as $a$, we get
$$
n\gg 1 \implies a_n\sim a_{n+1}\sim a \implies
a = \sqrt{8} + \dfrac54a \implies\frac14a = -\sqrt{8}\implies \bbox[1ex, border:solid 2pt #e10000]{a = -4\sqrt{8} = -8\sqrt{2}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is not hard to find the closed form for such sequences.  In your example:
$$
a_{n+1} =\frac45 a_n- \frac45 \sqrt{8}
$$
Inspired by the first term, let $a_n = \left( \frac45 \right)^n b_n$. Then 
$$
b_{n+1} \left( \frac45 \right)^{n+1}= b_n\frac45\left( \frac45 \right)^n - \frac45\sqrt{8}\\
b_{n+1} = b_n - \left( \frac54 \right)^{n}\sqrt{8}\\
b_n = b_0 - \sqrt{8}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \frac54 \right)^n
=b_0-4\sqrt{8}\left( \left( \frac54 \right)^{n}-1\right)
$$
Then 
$$
a_n = (a_0+4\sqrt{8})  \left( \frac45 \right)^n - 4 \sqrt{8}
$$
From this it is easy to see two things:

- The sequence **does converge**.
- The limit as $n\to\infty$ is $-4\sqrt{8}=-8\sqrt{2}$.

---

The second type of problem in your question, which is a delay equation,  is a heck of a lot harder in general.  Let me give an example so you can see why.

Problem: Find the $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ if 
$$f(x+1) = \frac12 f(x) + 3$$

This would seem simple:  $f(x)=6$ iterates to itself.  But you have been given no information about the behavior on the interval $o,1)$ and so the function could oscillate arbitrarily wildly on that interval (or do other awful tings) and not have a limit as $x\to\infty$ at all.

And in fact, if on $(0,1)$ yo have $f(x) = \tan 4\pi x$ then there won't be a limit.  But if you have on that interval
$f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ then even though the function has no limit as $x$ approaches any integer,  the limit as $x\to\infty$ does exist, and in fact is $6$.